# What's the best approach for two functions that use same code

Tags: php

I have 2 functions, they currently are doing the same thing.. In the future, it's quite possible that I need to add more functionality to one, but at the moment they act the same.

```
private function GetAnswerId( $value, $fieldId )
{
    // Code goes here, returns something      
}

private function GetQuestionId( $value, $fieldId ); // Currently same code as GetAnswerId... But might change later!
```

Is there some clever way of communicating to future developers that okay this function is currently the same implementation but in the future it won't be.. I don't want to just copy the code in GetAnswerId because that's drydicoulous. but I also don't want to use the same function because that's not forward thinking.

Virtual? Abstract? something like that :S

Comment: 140 lines means that something is wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I'd add some documentation to your function explaining that it is planned to change its behavior soon and make this function call and return `GetAnswerId`'s value.

```
private function GetQuestionId($value, $fieldId)
{
    return $this->GetAnswerId($value, $fieldId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. Just wondered if there was a clever keyword for it.. but not. :)

Answer (score 1):

Call your first function in your second function and expand from there:

```
private function GetQuestionId( $value, $fieldId )
{
     GetAnswerId( $value, $fieldId );

     // extra code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your duplicate functionality to base class:

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected function getId($value, $fieldId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Use one method `getId()` instead of `GetAnswerId()` and `GetQuestionId()`. Later, if you will decide change functionality for question ID, just add new method to current class:

```
class CurrentClass extend BaseClass
{
    protected function GetQuestionId($value, $fieldId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer man! :) I've marked the other guy as answer because it was just the quick win I needed. but this is nice!